# Calculate remaining balance on each row and insert to next id row on table with Trigger PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 table invoice_items, topup and topup_usage. On `invoice_items` there have `2 column` i use for trigger `amount` and `account_id`.

Table `invoice_items`:

```
id             account_id                   type     amount
200  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   topup       4
201  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   topup       7
202  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   topup       2
```

Table `topup_usage`:

```
id    id_topup    balance
```

Table and there initial of topup data `topup`:

```
id              account_id              amount_ds    status
322 ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163    4        active
323 ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163    7        active
324 ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163    2        active
```

have this situation, when a new data inserted on table invoice_item i get 2 data from column `account_id` and `amount` to insert table topup where `account_id` for `account_id` and `amount` for `amount_ds`. Then i do 2 transaction on my system where trigger when status is 'usage' from table `invoice_items` like this:

```
id             account_id                   type     amount
200  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   topup       4
201  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   topup       7
202  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   topup       2
203  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   usage       2
204  ac96c2bc-d4e3-4d75-9814-0186be8e0163   usage       3
```

to insert data on `topup_usage` what i try this happen:

```
id   topup_id  amount
399    322        2
400    322        3
```

I try to make topup_id 322 total is maximum 4 like on table topup (`amount_ds`), but there 5 total, when total usage is exceeded on topup_id is exceeded than 4 like 5 for example, it's make generate to next topup_id like this:

```
 id      topup_id    amount
 399       322        2
 400       322        2
 401       323        1
```

then for topup_id 323 calculated maximum 7, but as previously on topup_id 323 have max 6 amount left to use. Then if 7 inserted, like this

```
id      topup_id    amount
399       322         2
400       322         2
401       323         1
402       323         6
403       324         1
```

and i use trigger like this:

```
create or replace function topup_usage() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
  IF new.type = 'USAGE' THEN
    IF(SELECT notes  = 'true' FROM accounts WHERE accounts.id = new.account_id) THEN

    IF ((SELECT amount_ds FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id = new.account_id AND status = 'active' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) - new.amount < 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(id) > 1 FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id=new.account_id)) THEN
        INSERT INTO topup_usage (id_topup, balance)
        VALUES((SELECT id FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id = new.account_id and status = 'active' limit 1), (SELECT amount_ds FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id=new.account_id AND status='active' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) - (SELECT COALESCE(sum(balance), 0) FROM topup_usage WHERE id_topup=(SELECT id FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id=new.account_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) );

         INSERT INTO topup_usage (id_topup, balance)
          VALUES((SELECT id FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id = new.account_id and status = 'active' ORDER BY id ASC limit 1) + 1, new.amount - (SELECT balance FROM topup_usage WHERE id_topup=(SELECT id FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id=new.account_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)));

      ELSE
        INSERT INTO topup_usage (id_topup, balance)
        VALUES((SELECT id FROM topup WHERE topup.account_id = new.account_id and status = 'active' limit 1), new.amount);
      END IF;


      IF ((SELECT amount_ds FROM topup WHERE id =(SELECT id FROM topup WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY id ASC limit 1)) - (SELECT SUM(balance) FROM topup_usage WHERE id_topup=(SELECT id FROM topup WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY id ASC limit 1))) <= 0 THEN
          UPDATE topup SET status = 'finish' WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM topup WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY id ASC limit 1);
      END IF;

    END IF;
  END IF;
  return null;
END;
$$;
```

this result what happened to me:

```
id   topup_id  amount
399    322        2
400    322        3
```

not like this:

```
 id      topup_id    amount
 399       322         2
 400       322         2
 401       323         1
 402       323         6
 403       324         1
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what is the problem? Does the function you provided work? If it doesn't what problem do you have with it?

Comment: Oops, i have edited for the problem. the function work but the result doesn't what i want